# How to present a modal view controller on the iphone without a "current" view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to open the email view controller (`MFMailComposeViewController`), and everything I read suggests using `presentModalViewController:animated:`, which seems to need to be sent to a `UIViewController`.

For example, in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1), it says:

> Call the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of the current view controller, passing in the view controller you want to present modally.

But I don't have a "current view controller"! My app is otherwise entirely OpenGL, and my setup code looks like:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.view = [[IPhoneView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

[window addSubview: self.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and I set up the OpenGL context in the `IPhoneView` class.

I've found a number of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367348/how-to-get-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-uiview-via-code) asking how to get a `UIViewController` from a `UIView`, and the consensus seems to be: don't. So how can I open the email view controller with that nifty sliding animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do your own sliding animation of a view and just pass `MFMailComposeViewController` to it: [Hidden Drawer example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html)

See a similar sliding code here as well:  [How can I present a UIView from the bottom of the screen like a UIActionSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357034/how-can-i-present-a-uiview-from-the-bottom-of-the-screen-like-a-uiactionsheet/3357114#3357114)