# How to draw View Controller from the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to develop an app in Xcode. I am new in Objective C programming but so far I did OK. Today I got my first problem. I am trying to draw a transparent VC (View Controller) from the bottom up but I do not know how I can accomplish this. I know that drawing in iPhone begins from 0,0 coordinates from top left corner going right and down. Is there a way to kind of cheat and draw the VC from the bottom to top 70% covering the screen, just like the tools menu when swipe up on iPhone screen in iOS 7.x.x

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to make a view that pops up from the bottom (or you can drag up from the bottom)? Doing what I think you want has nothing to do with drawing from the bottom, or the fact that iOS has the 0,0 point at the top left.

Comment: you need not draw a view controller. You can always present a view controller through animation. "presentViewController:animated: completion:" and also this link helps https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I am trying to pop a view from the bottom i did manage to make it to come from the top. However, when I change the height and width it concentrates in the top left corner, this is why I thought it has something to do with drawing on the screen

Comment: Don't change the height or width, change its position. Start it with a frame that's offscreen to the bottom, then move it up.

Comment: This is what I was trying to find a way to do - change the position by centralize it or something. Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you want to present a screen from the bottom up, you can check out this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357034/how-can-i-present-a-uiview-from-the-bottom-of-the-screen-like-a-uiactionsheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres one solution:

1. Create the view as a subview of the main view in this controller.

   ```
   self.rolloutView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, heightYouWant)];
   ```
2. When the user takes the action, call this function

   ```
   -(void)toggleView:(id)sender
   {   
       __block CGRect frame = self.rolloutView.frame;
        // Check if the frame's origin.y is at the bottom of the screen
       if(self.rolloutView.frame.origin.y == [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height){
           // if it is, reduce it by the height of the view you eventually want
            frame.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-heightYouWant ;
       }
       else{
           // else push it down again
           frame.size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
       }
       [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                animations:^{
                    self.rolloutView.frame = frame;
                }
                    completion:nil];
   }
   ```

I have not compiled the code but it should give you the idea on what i am suggesting

Comment: Thanks I will try it first thing when I get home and let you know.

Comment: Where do I add thiis code in the main VC is it in particular function in the main VC or i must add it to AppDelegate in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions                                                                                                 "self.rolloutView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, heightYouWant)];"